# Accessing FreeMarker sequence with variable as index parameter

Tags: freemarker

My FreeMarker template contains a sequence defined as follows:

```
<#assign monthsLong = ["Nope", "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", 
                       "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", 
                       "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]>
```

How can I access a single item of `monthsLong` using a variable as index? Using a number directly or a variable as index parameter works as expected:

```
<#assign i=1> ${monthsLong[i]}
${monthsLong[1]}
```

But I can't use a variable from my model like this without getting an exception:

```
<#assign index>${selectedMonth}</#assign>
${monthsLong[index]}
```

How can I use the value of `${selectedMonth}` to access a specific element of my sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the index must be number, but if you print something and capture the output (that's what you did), then it will be a string. You probably just wanted `<#assign index = selectedMonth>`, which doesn't do any conversion. (Furthermore in your example you could just write  `${monthsLong[selectedMonth]}`, but I assume the example is a simplification.)

(If, by any chance, `selectedMonth` is also a string, and you can't change that, you can write `${monthsLong[selectedMonth?number]}`.)